# Set bottom to 100% of own height

Tags: css

I want to set an element so that it hides from page view and it's top touches exactly the bottom of page (the element is out of sight). I was doing `botttom: -66px;'` at first when the element had constant height of 66px. But now I need this for an element of any size.

If I do `bottom: -100%;` it sets it to 100% of the size of parent. How do set it to -100% of its own height.

Comment: You can try with a wrapper div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for "`position: fixed`" and "`transform: translateY(100%);`". This allows you to move your div out of your viewport by 100%, independent of the height of the div.

Example:

```
div {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```